# activity redirection problem in android

Tags: android

hi all 
i have an app with 3 activity. if i launch the app the first time it have to redirect to second activity from first activity. after the first time launch the app it have to go to third activity from first activity. how to do that? please help me. is there way to without using database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a boolean flag in the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). On loading your application you can read that flag.

- If it is null: goto Activity 2 **and** set the flag to true
- If it exists: goto Activity 3